# Using JDO 3.0 with App Engine and Gradle

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, guice, jdo, datanucleus

I am trying to migrate to JDO 3.0 in a cloud endpoint Framework 2.0 and Guice environment. I am using the datanucleus Eclipse plugin.

I checked the following documentation:

[Using JDO 3.0 with App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/jdo/overview-dn2)

There is only a Ant or Maven docu. In my Gradle env, when starting the appengine  standard server in eclipse, i get the error appended below.

Does anyone have a hint? Maybe the copytarget not set in Gradle build script correctly?

```
Sep 24, 2017 4:58:19 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNUNG: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Sep 24, 2017 4:58:20 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFORMATION: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\Users\MMM\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'D:\workspaces\tatonlinews\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\justMapMeEndpoints\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
Sep 24, 2017 4:58:20 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFORMATION: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Sep 24, 2017 2:58:20 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFORMATION: jetty-6.1.x
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (DataNucleus.Plugin).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Sep 24, 2017 2:58:23 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNUNG: failed guiceFilter: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: A property named javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass must be specified, or a jar file with a META-INF/services/javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory entry must be in the classpath, or a property named javax.jdo.option.PersistenceUnitName must be specified.
NestedThrowables:
javax.jdo.JDOException: Errors were encountered when initialising the specified MetaData. See the nested exceptions for details
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Errors were encountered when initialising the specified MetaData. See the nested exceptions for details
  at com.sky.tatOnline.server.guice.DispatchServletModule.getPersistenceManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
  at com.sky.tatOnline.server.guice.DispatchServletModule.getPersistenceManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
  while locating javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory
    for parameter 1 at com.sky.tatOnline.server.db.GAEDatastore.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating com.sky.tatOnline.server.db.GAEDatastore
  at com.sky.tatOnline.server.guice.DispatchServletModule.configureServlets(DispatchServletModule.java:92)
  while locating com.sky.tatOnline.server.db.Datastore
    for parameter 1 at com.sky.tatOnline.server.mapMeEndpoints.MapMeFriendsV1.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating com.sky.tatOnline.server.mapMeEndpoints.MapMeFriendsV1

1 error
Sep 24, 2017 2:58:23 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNUNG: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@3c9bfddc{/,D:\workspaces\tatonlinews\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\justMapMeEndpoints}
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: A property named javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass must be specified, or a jar file with a META-INF/services/javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory entry must be in the classpath, or a property named javax.jdo.option.PersistenceUnitName must be specified.
NestedThrowables:
javax.jdo.JDOException: Errors were encountered when initialising the specified MetaData. See the nested exceptions for details
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Errors were encountered when initialising the specified MetaData. See the nested exceptions for details
  at com.sky.tatOnline.server.guice.DispatchServletModule.getPersistenceManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
  at com.sky.tatOnline.server.guice.DispatchServletModule.getPersistenceManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
  while locating javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory
    for parameter 1 at com.sky.tatOnline.server.db.GAEDatastore.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating com.sky.tatOnline.server.db.GAEDatastore
  at com.sky.tatOnline.server.guice.DispatchServletModule.configureServlets(DispatchServletModule.java:92)
  while locating com.sky.tatOnline.server.db.Datastore
    for parameter 1 at com.sky.tatOnline.server.mapMeEndpoints.MapMeFriendsV1.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating com.sky.tatOnline.server.mapMeEndpoints.MapMeFriendsV1

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:104)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.guice.ServiceMap.get(ServiceMap.java:69)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.guice.GuiceEndpointsServlet.createService(GuiceEndpointsServlet.java:37)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet.createSystemService(EndpointsServlet.java:128)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet.init(EndpointsServlet.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.init(ServletDefinition.java:121)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.init(ManagedServletPipeline.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:268)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:284)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:271)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:359)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:223)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:214)
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: A property named javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass must be specified, or a jar file with a META-INF/services/javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory entry must be in the classpath, or a property named javax.jdo.option.PersistenceUnitName must be specified.
NestedThrowables:
javax.jdo.JDOException: Errors were encountered when initialising the specified MetaData. See the nested exceptions for details
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Errors were encountered when initialising the specified MetaData. See the nested exceptions for details
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:861)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1099)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:919)
    at com.sky.tatOnline.server.guice.DispatchServletModule.getPersistenceManagerFactory(DispatchServletModule.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:128)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$ReflectionProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:299)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:172)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOException: Errors were encountered when initialising the specified MetaData. See the nested exceptions for details
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Errors were encountered when initialising the specified MetaData. See the nested exceptions for details
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.initialiseMetaData(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:611)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:504)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:294)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:128)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:844)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Errors were encountered when initialising the specified MetaData. See the nested exceptions for details
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.initialiseFileMetaDataForUse(MetaDataManager.java:1151)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadPersistenceUnit(MetaDataManager.java:986)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.initialiseMetaData(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:601)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Found Meta-Data for class com.sky.tatOnline.server.db.entities.CountryBoundingBox but this class is not enhanced!! Please enhance the class before running DataNucleus.
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.initialiseClassMetaData(MetaDataManager.java:2593)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.initialiseFileMetaData(MetaDataManager.java:2544)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.initialiseFileMetaDataForUse(MetaDataManager.java:1140)
    ... 90 more

Sep 24, 2017 2:58:23 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFORMATION: Started SelectChannelConnector@localhost:8080
Sep 24, 2017 2:58:23 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFORMATION: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8080/
Sep 24, 2017 2:58:23 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFORMATION: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
Sep 24, 2017 4:58:23 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFORMATION: Dev App Server is now running
```

Here is my gradle script:

```
buildscript {    // Configuration for building
  repositories {
    jcenter()    // Bintray's repository - a fast Maven Central mirror & more
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+'    // latest App Engine Gradle tasks
    // Endpoints Frameworks Gradle plugin
    classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:+'
  }
}

repositories {   // repositories for Jar's you access in your code
  maven {
    url 'https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com'             // Google's mirror of Maven Central
//   url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' // SNAPSHOT Repository (if needed)
  }
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'                              // standard Java tasks
apply plugin: 'war'                               // standard Web Archive plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'  // App Engine tasks

// [START apply_endpoints-framework-server]
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'
// [END apply_endpoints-framework-server]

dependencies {
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version:'2.5'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine:1.9.54'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-jsr107cache:1.9.54'

  // Add your dependencies here.
    compile group: 'com.google.endpoints', name: 'endpoints-framework', version: '+'
    compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version: '3.0', classifier: 'no_aop'
    compile group: 'net.sf.jsr107cache', name: 'jsr107cache', version: '1.1'

     //https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management
     compile group: 'com.google.endpoints', name: 'endpoints-management-control-appengine', version: '1.0.0-beta.11'
     compile group: 'com.google.endpoints', name: 'endpoints-framework-auth', version: '1.0.0-beta.11'

     compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev110-1.22.0'
     //GCM:
     compile 'com.google.gcm:gcm-server:1.0.0'

     compile 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.6.0'

     compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.45'
     compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'

     //Facebook Authenticator:
     compile 'com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:2.7.0-rc1'

     compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:1.7.4'

     compile 'com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:3.0'
     compile 'com.google.inject:guice:4.0'

     compile 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework-guice:2.0.0-beta.4'
     compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.16'

     // Persistence
     compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm:4.0'
     compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jpa:3.1.3'
     compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jdo:3.1.3'
     compile 'com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine:2.1.2'
     compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:3.1.3'
     compile 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec:1.0'
     compile 'javax.jdo:jdo-api:3.0.1'
     compile 'javax.transaction:jta:1.1'
}

appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration

  run {      // local (dev_appserver) configuration (standard environments only)
    port = 8080                 // default
  }


  deploy {   // deploy configuration
    stopPreviousVersion = true  // default - stop the current version
    promote = true              // default - & make this the current version
    version = '90'
    project = 'appname'
  }
}

// [START endpoints-server]
endpointsServer {
  // Endpoints Framework Plugin server-side configuration
  hostname = "appname.appspot.com"
}

group = 'com.example.appengine'   // Generated output GroupId
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'          // Version in generated output

sourceCompatibility = 1.7  // App Engine Standard uses Java 7
targetCompatibility = 1.7  // App Engine Standard uses Java 7
```

here is my jdoconfig.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig_3_0.xsd">
<!-- xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">  alte config-->
   <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
       <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass" value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/>

       <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>
       <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>

       <property name="javax.jdo.option.DatastoreReadTimeoutMillis" value="5000"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.DatastoreWriteTimeoutMillis" value="10000"/>

       <!-- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions 
        Using cross-group transactions in JDO and JPA
       -->
       <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="true"/>


       <!--
        http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview.html#Datastore_Performance_Features
        Do not use EVENTUAL consistency, because you can not read and write in a transaction
        Default is strong Consistency, so the following property must not be defined!
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency" value="EVENTUAL" />-->
       <!-- <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency" value="STRONG " />-->
   </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

and here is my datanucleus persistence.xml:
i trie the following folders where i put this file:
- src\main\webapp\META-INF\persistence.xml
- src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\persistence.xml
- src\main\java\META-INF\persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
        <mapping-file>myclass.jdo</mapping-file>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---

error message using datanucleus plugin v4. an v4 version of datanucleus.core.jar...

16:32:15,937 (main) WARN  [DataNucleus.General] - Extension Point "org.datanucleus.implementation_creator" not registered, but plugin "org.datanucleus.enhancer" defined in file:/C:/Users/MMM/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-enhancer/3.1.1/b141c67d55cc19f14639f091b84e692e2198dc50/datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar refers to it.
16:32:15,998 (main) ERROR [DataNucleus.Persistence] - User-defined type mapping class "org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.Collection" was not found. Please check the mapping file class specifications and your CLASSPATH. The class must be in the CLASSPATH.
16:32:16,015 (main) ERROR [DataNucleus.Persistence] - User-defined type mapping class "org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.List" was not found. Please check the mapping file class specifications and your CLASSPATH. The class must be in the CLASSPATH.
16:32:16,028 (main) ERROR [DataNucleus.Persistence] - User-defined type mapping class "org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.Set" was not found. Please check the mapping file class specifications and your CLASSPATH. The class must be in the CLASSPATH.
16:32:16,064 (main) INFO  [DataNucleus.Enhancer] - DataNucleus Enhancer (version 4.1.17) for API "JDO"
16:32:16,092 (main) ERROR [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Unknown tag : "faceted-project"
16:32:16,093 (main) ERROR [DataNucleus.MetaData] - An error occurred while parsing <"faceted-project"> nested within "
" for URI ""
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown tag : "faceted-project"
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.metadata.JDOMetaDataHandler.startElement(JDOMetaDataHandler.java:1242)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:380)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:619)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3129)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.xml.MetaDataParser.parseMetaDataStream(MetaDataParser.java:283)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.xml.MetaDataParser.parseMetaDataURL(MetaDataParser.java:144)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.metadata.JDOMetaDataManager.parseFile(JDOMetaDataManager.java:263)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.loadFiles(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:1426)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.loadMetadataFiles(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:522)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:731)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:500)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1152)

Comment: Class is not enhanced; seems pretty clear to me. Enhance the classes and use the enhanced versions at runtime. Also you need EITHER `jdoconfig.xml` OR `persistence.xml` NOT BOTH!

Comment: i am using the datanucleus plugin in eclipse. Right clicking on the eclipse project -> datanucleus -> has the option "run enhancer tool". Why does this not work? How to enhance the classes?

Comment: You enhance using the Eclipse plugin, Maven plugin, Ant, or calling it via Java. And where are you putting the ENHANCED classes? and what classes are you using at RUNTIME?

Comment: I currently want to migrate to cloud endpoint Framework 2.0. Before that, i was using eclipse with the google app engine plugin. The enhancement of the classes was done automatically. Now this does not work anymore. I am new to gradle and the datanucleus Plugin. I am not sure what to do, to automatically enhance my classe like it was in the old version.

Comment: Since you dont say what version of DataNucleus, or its Eclipse plugin you are using how could anyone say what you need to do ? And by the sound of it it is all ancient history versions of DataNucleus that are no longer supported.

Comment: you mean the datanucleus plugin is ancient history?
(My db classes are lying in 'build\classes\db\entities')

Comment: I mean the VERSION of it that you are using, which you don't tell us. Judging by most other things "appengine" it involves using ancient versions. For example the only versions mentioned in your post says DataNucleus v3.1.3, which is not supported any longer. Doesn't mean it can't work but you're unlikely to get support, and need to debug things yourself using LOGs

Comment: in my gradle skript i am using:
compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jpa:3.1.3'
compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jdo:3.1.3'
compile 'com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine:2.1.2'
compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:3.1.3'
compile 'javax.jdo:jdo-api:3.0.1'

Datanucleus Eclipse plugin version 4.0.0.release

Comment: i switched to the version:
  compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jpa:5.1.2'
  compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jdo:5.1.2'
  compile 'com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine:2.1.2'

now the question is:
1. how to enhance classes
2. how can i recognize, whether the classes are enhanced

Comment: You enhance classes in the way that the documentation tells you, using Maven plugin, Eclipse plugin, Ant task, or whatever. http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jdo/enhancer.html  You recognize if a class is enhanced by using a decompiler (like the docs tells you, see that link), or by using "javap" which shows what methods a class has

Comment: to summarize: I did not get the classes enhanced. Why is the enhancement so complicated with cloud framework? Further more i think the eclipse datanucleus plugin is not useful when using google cloud framework with eclipse. i think it is outdated and should only be used with the appengine sdk which is not available anymore with google cloud framework.

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/guides/eclipse.html  -> does not work. Does nothing...

Comment: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jdo/tools.html#eclipse works for me, and you use the LOG when you have problems with it. But then there are ample other ways of invoking the enhancer so its up to you which you use ...

Comment: i messed around with the datanucleus plugin and added other versions of the neccessary jars. Now finally the plugin shows some reaction in the datanucleus log. Does anyone know what this means:

Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Error reading the Meta-Data input "Content ist nicht zulässig in Prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content ist nicht zulässig in Prolog.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)

Comment: You have some XML file input? `persistence.xml`? JDO XML metadata?

Comment: i am using no persistence.xml. Before migrating to endpoints framework 2.0, my code worked fine with the jdoconfig.xml (see above).But i tried to generate a persistence.xml with the datanucleus plugin. With the generated persistence.xml in the META_INF directory i get the same error. Could you tell me which jars you added to the runtime classpath in the datanucleus plugin config? I am using datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar, asm-5.0.0.jar, hsqldb-2.4.0.jar, jdo-api-3.1.jar, datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar , datanucleus-api-3.1.3.jar and the datanucleus eclipse plugin in version 4.0.0.release

Comment: For enhancement you need ASM, datanucleus-api-jdo, datanucleus-core and javax.jdo (jdo-api). And if you are using v3.x you use eclipse plugin 3.x, but as said, all of that is ancient and unsupported now.

Comment: please clarify "all of that is ancient and unsupported now". You mean datanucleus per se is unsupported or datanucleus version v3? I just tried datanucleus version v4 (that means eclipse datanucleus plugin v4 (newest available), datanucleus-core-4.1.17.jar, datanucleus-api-jdo-4.2.5). I added the error message above.

Comment: This page http://www.datanucleus.org/documentation/products.html  tells you what versions of DataNucleus are "supported".

Comment: why does the plugin logs this confusing messages:" 
ERROR [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Unknown tag : "faceted-project"
ERROR [DataNucleus.MetaData] - An error occurred while parsing <"faceted-project"> nested within "org.datanucleus.metadata.FileMetaData@38082d64" for URI ""
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown tag : "faceted-project"

Comment: or WARN  [DataNucleus.General] - Extension Point "org.datanucleus.implementation_creator" not registered, but plugin "org.datanucleus.enhancer" defines in datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar refers to it.
These error messages are saying nothing to me...

Comment: the lates version of org.datanucleus:datanucleus-enhancer is 3.1.1. Should there not be a version 5.1.2?
I use Gradle and i have this defined:
compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-enhancer:3.1.1'

Comment: Why you have some faceted-project only you can say, your files. And no there should not be some later version of the enhancer since that is part of datanucleus-core later on. Docs say this clearly.

Comment: What does "faceted-project" and the RuntimeExceptiuon" means in the context of datanucleus? My package structure is the same as with the appengine plugin where the enhancement worked fine in the past. Is it a problem with Gradle? Should i use Maven? Maven seems to be better documented than Gradle.

Comment: As already said, only you would know what "faceted-project" means; it is nothing to do with JDO or DataNucleus - would have thought your exception, stack trace, log tells you where it comes from. How you do enhancement is up to you ... it is a Java process, so whether you use Maven, Gradle, Eclipse, command line, Ant or whatever it is the same thing. You just have to pass things in to that Java process.

Comment: how does the datanucelus plugin know which classes to enhance? I added the relevant file extension class in the datanucleus config (class, xml and jdo). My class path contains  "myproject\bin", 
 "myproject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes", "user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1". The plugin generates a file "5311549000680550596.flf" which can't be found after running the plugin. The log contains the following message: "Reading fileListFile: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\enhancer-5311549000680550596.flf".

Comment: Depends which "plugin" you're referring to. The DataNucleus docs tell you how you specify which classes to enhance. Maybe a persistence-unit defining classes and mapping files, or a directory. "DataNucleus" does NOT generate any "flf" file.